# Can't Login using ImapX from Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, imap, azure-webjobs, gmail-imap, imapx

I have an application that uses the Imapx library (https://imapx.codeplex.com/) to connect to a Gmail account to download and process email messages. The application works fine on my PC, but when I publish my application to an Azure WebJob, the Connect() succeeds but the Login() authentications fails. My Gmail account is set to allow access to less secure apps. Is there something in Azure that would prevent authentication using the Imap protocol? Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide exception Message/StackTrace and logs: https://imapx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging%20ImapX

Comment: FYI, got it working. I had to unlock the Captcha requirements on my account. (http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha). Thanks for the advice on setting Debug on the client.